# Dialog box shown furtively when called at WPF application startup in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, startup

I've a problem when showing a dialog box in a **WPF** startup application in `App.xaml.cs`.

I'm checking if another instance is running then if yes, I display a dialog box to the end user to inform him. After that I exit the application. This check is done in `App.xaml.cs` constructor.

All is working except that the dialog box is displayed but very furtively, then the application exits. So the end user have no time to read the dialog box content.

This is my code :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static Mutex _mutex = null;
    // Application GUID
    // Generator used : https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx
    private string _applicationGUID = "1a23e856-681d-4680-9ae8-1ffc01cfe136";

    public App()
    {
        bool isNewInstance;

        _mutex = new Mutex(true, _applicationGUID, out isNewInstance);

        if (!isNewInstance)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An application is already running...\nPlease close it and restart", "My Program", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            App.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to test the `MessageBoxResult result`, then put the code in the `OnStartup` method overrided, but without success.

**How can I do to let the dialog box remaining until the end user clicks OK ?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try to place the code for message box showing in `OnStartup` method?

Comment: Yes I did, same problem.

Comment: Have you tried to set `owner` window explicitly to `null`? I guess that you don't have main window when show the message box

Comment: Indeed in the App constructor, there is no Window available not yet created. Only a Splashscreen shown at the same time than the dialog box.

Comment: public App()
        {
            bool isNewInstance=false; // should assigne
            _mutex = new Mutex(true, _applicationGUID, out isNewInstance);
            if (!isNewInstance)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An application is already running...\nPlease close it and restart", "My Program", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                App.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () => {
                 await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000); App.Current.Shutdown();
                }); 
            }
        }

Comment: . @Mitra M, I don't want to wait 5 seconds, but hold the Dialog box until the end user click OK.